# Group By/Order By Two Columns - Get Data Without Losing Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table `number_color_style` with the structure as shown below.

[image: Table Strcture]

This table contains data as shown below(8 rows)

[image: Table Data]

What I want as I output is All records grouped by `number_color_id` , `number_style_id`

I tried below query

```
SELECT *
FROM `number_color_style`
GROUP BY `number_color_id` , `number_style_id`
```

It gives me output but some rows are missing

[image: Result]

What I want is **four set of data** without missing a single row(should contain all 8 rows).
EG:

- 1st set where `number_color_id = 1` , `number_style_id = 1`
- 2nd set where `number_color_id = 1` , `number_style_id = 2`
- 3rd set where `number_color_id = 2` , `number_style_id = 1`
- 4th set where `number_color_id = 2` , `number_style_id = 2`

How can I do it ?

Create table query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `number_color_style` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `img` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `number_color_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number_style_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Some sample data

```
INSERT INTO `jink`.`number_color_style` (`id`, `img`, `number_color_id`, `number_style_id`, `number_id`) VALUES (NULL, 'img1.png', '1', '1', '10'), (NULL, 'img2.png', '1', '1', '10'), (NULL, 'img3.png', '1', '2', '10'), (NULL, 'img4.png', '2', '1', '10'), (NULL, 'img5.png', '2', '1', '10');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display all 8 set according to number_color_id and number_style_id, should use order by instead of group by.

```
SELECT *
FROM `number_color_style`
ORDER BY `number_color_id` , `number_style_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an aggregate function when you use 'group by', such as count (*). It might be that you are confusing 'group by' with 'order by'.

One possible query would be:

```
select number_color_id, number_style_id, count (*)
from number_color_style
group by number_color_id, number_style_id
```

But I think that you want

```
select *
from number_color_style
order by number_color_id, number_style_id
```